# WP-admin does not redirect to login page

Tags: wordpress

If I browse to my wordpress wp-admin directory,  I recall that I used to get redirected to the login page if I was not already logged in.  Now I get the standard wordpress page not found error.  I'm not aware of changing any configuration that would alter this behavior.   Are there things that could have been done to stop the auto redirection from occurring?  Or something I need to re-enable or reverse to get that behaviour back?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally it is a practice used for security reasons, because you see if I know that you are using Wordpress then I can easily guess all your URLs, login URL, Admin URL, Register URL, etc...

There are some plugins that would do that for you, [IThemes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) is an example.

> Themes Security hides common WordPress security vulnerabilities,
>   preventing attackers from learning too much about your site and away
>   from sensitive areas like your site’s login, admin, etc.
>
> - Changes the URLs for WordPress dashboard areas including login, admin
>     and more

So the short answer is, yes you can configure it one way or another.

To Undo it, configure it again